# Stop event from happening when pressing a button

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am not sure why this is happening, but when a user taps on a UI button on the screen, `TapStart.Invoke();` is getting triggered. It should only trigger when the screen is tapped, and the tap isn't on a button.

I assumed that this would stop it: `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == null` but it doesn't seem to be doing so.

```
void Update() {
  if (Input.touches.Length == 1) {
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && HasStarted) {
      Swipe.Invoke(StartPosition, touch.position);
      IsSwiping = true;
    }

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
      if (!IsSwiping && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == null) {
        if (GameManager.Instance.Toast.ResetReady) {
          TapRestart.Invoke();
        } else {
          TapStart.Invoke();
        }
      }
      IsSwiping = false;
      HasStarted = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` is not used for that. `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Programmer I have tried using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject` and it is still triggering `TapStart.Invoke()`

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the duplicate first since there are multiple ways to use that depending on if it is desktop or mobile.  If that doesn't work then you have to add EDIT to your question, followed by your new code to show how you're using it otherwise there is no way to know what's the problem.

Comment: Okay, the issue is that `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)` is returning false when I tap on a button. I think it should be returning true...

Comment: It looks like it is always false because it is in `TouchPahse.Ended`. If I move it to `TouchPahse.Began` and save the boolean and check in ended it seems to work.

Comment: Use `IsPointerOverGameObject` without the argument when checking it in `TouchPahse.Ended`